# Negative margin with float for two-column layout

Tags: css, css-float, margin

I saw two column layout made as following way, but I didn't understand why it works.
So what actually does the `.col-sub` do? If I remove `margin-left:-100%` in `.col-sub`, the Sub Content will fall down. If I remove `float: left` in it, the Sub Content can't show. What does margin-left and float do here?

Demo can also be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/yougen/ATNh9/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="col-main">Main Content</div>
        <div class="col-sub">Sub Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
       * {
            padding:0;
            margin: 0;
        }

       .wrapper {
           margin: 0px auto;
           width: 960px;
           text-align: center;
           line-height: 580px;
       }

       .col-main {
           width:100%;
           height:580px;
           float: left;
           background-color: #f16529;
           border: solid 1px #000;
       }

       .col-sub {
           float: left;
           margin-left: -100%;/** -960px **/
           width: 350px;
           height: 580px;
           background-color: #f0dddd;
       }
```

Comment: I stumbled upon the same question a while ago. This smashing magazine article is a good read : http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Comment: @Varinder, I also read the article, really a good one. But in the article, it only mentioned both element be float, and set negative margin opposite to float. In my case, I set float and negative margin on the same element and the margin is not opposite to the float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your browser’s developer tools, and play around with the `margin-left` value of the sub content – decrease (or rather increase?) it slowly from `-100%` to `0%`, and you will see it move across the orange main content, then end up under it.

Under it is where it normally would go (without negative margin), because it is floated left, but it’s position in the DOM is after the main content. It *would* go right next to the also left-floated main content, if there was any space – but there isn’t any, because the main content is 100% wide.

By introducing a negative margin, that space is “created”. The negative margin “overwrites” the right edge of the element before the sub content, making the whole thing act as if that right edge was further to the left. When the right margin reaches `-100%`, it is as if the whole main element “wasn’t there” from the point of view of the left sub content – so it happily takes it’s place *above* the main content to the left of the wrapper element.

Comment: Really appreaciate your answer. BTW, could you give some advise about mastering css, since I really don't negative margin will "creat space". Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Well, “mastering CSS” is quite a broad topic … for which I can only advise you to read tutorials, try stuff on your own and see how other sites are achieving specific effects. As for the specific  question regarding negative margins – what exactly is the problem?